# js concatenates an integer value to an integer array element instead of adding them together

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following is a js function where I am trying to add the amt input from user, to pmt_arry[month] and pmt_arry[13] integer array elements. But, instead of adding the numeric value of amt input, js simply concatenates it as string. I don't understand how js thinks. I am including the console output as well further below. As can be seen in the output, the two payments of 225 each should be added to pmt_arry[11] and pmt[13] to make them 450 each but js simply concatenates them as 225225 and 225225. Please help.

```js
function updCurryrPmtData(username, month, amt, callback) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM havuzs_sakinleri WHERE isim = ?', [username], function(err, rows) {
        if (err)  // If error in updating the database, display error message.
            throw err;
        rows.forEach((row)=> {
            pmt_arry = [0, row.ay1_odemesi, row.ay2_odemesi, row.ay3_odemesi, row.ay4_odemesi,
                row.ay5_odemesi, row.ay6_odemesi, row.ay7_odemesi, row.ay8_odemesi, row.ay9_odemesi,
                row.ay10_odemesi, row.ay11_odemesi, row.ay12_odemesi, row.toplam_odenen_tl];
            pmt_arry = pmt_arry.map(Number);
            console.log('pmt_arry before: ', pmt_arry);
            pmt_arry[month] = pmt_arry[month] + amt;    
            pmt_arry[13] = pmt_arry[13] + amt;    
            console.log('pmt_arry after: ', pmt_arry);
            calcTotPayable(username, function(response) {
                var totpayable_curryr = response - amt;
                console.log('totpayable_curryr: ', totpayable_curryr );  
                var sql = "UPDATE havuzs_sakinleri SET ay1_odemesi = ?, ay2_odemesi = ?, ay3_odemesi = ?, ay4_odemesi = ?, " +
                            "ay5_odemesi = ?, ay6_odemesi = ?, ay7_odemesi = ?, ay8_odemesi = ?, ay9_odemesi = ?, ay10_odemesi = ?, " + 
                            "ay11_odemesi = ?, ay12_odemesi = ?, toplam_odenen_tl = ?, aidat_bakiye = ? WHERE isim = ? ";
                con.query(sql, [pmt_arry[1], pmt_arry[2], pmt_arry[3], pmt_arry[4], pmt_arry[5], pmt_arry[6], pmt_arry[7], 
                        pmt_arry[8], pmt_arry[9], pmt_arry[10], pmt_arry[11], pmt_arry[12], pmt_arry[13], totpayable_curryr, 
                        username], function(err, res) {
                    if (err)  // If error in updating the database, display error message.
                        {   throw err;
                            status_message=('Aylik aidat güncellenirken sorun oluştu.');
                        }  
                    else  // If update is successful, display a message.
                        status_message = ("Bu site sakininin aylık ödemeleri güncellendi!");
                    return callback(status_message);
                });
            });   
        });     
    });    
};
```

Following is the console output before and after the addition.
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure try and convert `amt` into Number before adding it.

Comment: amt is already an integer. Nonetheless, I have tried converting it by 'amt = amt.map(Number);'. But, node.js doesn't like it, it says 'TypeError: amt.map is not a function'.

Comment: I think `amt` is not an array that is why you can't use `map()`. Try and do `amt = Number(amt)`.

Comment: I am a beginner but your level of js must be much more advanced. It works. I will add this to my important js tips-notes. Much appreciated, thanks.